# Why Laravel Auth::check always return false?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I am making an API for an existing database. I noticed the problem first when I saw that Auth::attempt always returned false. Since I have implemented my own SHA1 hashing provider I thought that might be the problem.

But I tried Hash::make('test') and it gave me 'a94a8fe5ccb19ba61c4c0873d391e987982fbbd3'. Then I tried Hash::make($client->pwd) and it gave me the same hash. Correct so far. Finally I did

```
if (Hash::check('test', $cli->pwd))
{
    [...]
}
```

and it returned false. From the looks of it the problem isn't my hashing provider and I guess this is also why Auth::attempt is failing. Can anyone tell me why ?

Comment: Auth::attempt() will hash the password itself, so it is probably re-hashing your "hashed" password

Comment: Did you integrate you custom hashing provider into Auth? Because that hash doesn't look as a BCrypt hash.

Comment: Oops, error on my part. I changed it to if (Hash::check('test', $cli->pwd)). Still returning false. And yes I think I got the integration right, it's SHA1 because my database passwords are not bcrypt hashes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was on my end. I misunderstood the concept of Eloquent. I had to change in my UserInterface class, the one my user model mapped to, getAuthIdentifier() to return "id" which is the PrimaryKey of my table. I though the getAuthIdentifier() was the "username" of the table.